# Unable to set menu for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu, oncreateoptionsmenu

```
Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Log.i("frag", "onCreate");
}


 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_initiate_chat, container, false);

    bindViews(view);

    setUpClickListener();

    setUpCategories(view);

    return view;
}

 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_inititate_chat, menu);
    Log.i("frag", "onCreateOptionsMenu");
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i("frag", "onOptionsItemSelected");
    final int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.send:
            sendIssue();
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I am unable to set a menu for my fragment.I have used the  setHasOptionsMenu(true); but it still doesn't make a difference.

My fragment xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bgGrey"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/toolbarTextColor" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/categories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>`
```

The menu item menu_inititate_chat.xml

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <item
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/send"
    android:icon="@drawable/send"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
    </menu>`
```

The activity which contains this fragment does not included a toolbar of its own.

Comment: The standard options menu only works on an `ActionBar`, or the support version thereof. If you want a menu to show on an arbitrary `Toolbar`, you'll have to put it there yourself. Have a look at the `Toolbar#inflateMenu()` and `Toolbar#setOnMenuItemClickListener()` methods.

Comment: @MikeM. yep that was the one, could you write the same as an answer so i can mark it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard Options Menu only works with an `ActionBar`, or the support version thereof.

If you want a menu to show on an arbitrary `Toolbar`, you can just put it there yourself. The `Toolbar#inflateMenu()` method can replace the menu inflation you currently have in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, and the `Toolbar#setOnMenuItemClickListener()` method can set a listener to replace the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method's function.

Alternatively, you could try setting the `Toolbar` as the `Activity`'s support `ActionBar`, if your design allows, and stick with the standard Options Menu setup, though that's kinda clunky, and might be a little error-prone.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using ToolBar in your Fragment ,then you can do it this way:

```
 toolBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.delete_address_menu);
 toolBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks but another guy answered it first so i had to mark his as the right answer but this is exactly what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_inititate_chat, menu);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your onOptionsItemSelected like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i("frag", "onOptionsItemSelected");
    final int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.send:
            sendIssue();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```